# Log message: org.geotools.renderer.style: null input stream, could not load the font

Tags: geotools

Currently I am migrating a project to Java 11. In this project, we are using GeoTools to create a PDF file with geometries inside. For this PDF file we use a special font which is not available in the system. Since Java 11 we store this font in the resources and load it at runtime. Since the migration to Java 11, the following message appears in the log:

```
org.geotools.renderer.style: null input stream, could not load the font
```

However, the PDF file is created without any problems. The font is loaded via Spring Boot using @Value as resource. The font is created as follows:

```
PDFont fontSourceSansProBold = PDTrueTypeFont.load(doc, ressourceSourceSansProBold.getInputStream(), WinAnsiEncoding.INSTANCE);
```

Has anyone had similar problems before? What was the solution, if any?

Thank you!

Comment: I think you'll need to stick a debugger on it and see exactly what's happening - I've had no issues with similar code but I don't use non-system fonts

Comment: My biggest problem is that the error does not occur locally where I could debug. It only occurs deployed on a Unix machine. 
But thanks for the idea.

Comment: I hate it when that happens - may be more System.out.println statements will help?

Comment: I have already done that and it had helped conditionally. So I came across some places where fonts are loaded using a string that only represents the font family. Namely like this:
styleBuilder.createFont("Source Sans Pro", false, true, 25)

In addition, you will find the following class when googling:
https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/master/modules/library/render/src/main/java/org/geotools/renderer/style/FontCache.java

Comment: In this, exactly the described error is thrown if the font cannot be found in the cache. So my idea was to change all places to get the font from our resources, because we don't have the font on the system and so nothing can be found in any cache. 
Unfortunately, that didn't help either, so I asked the question here.